# App calls Method on mouse click. How can I stop it?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, method-call

So I am pretty new to Xcode and Objective C, I've been using it about 2 weeks now.  I am building an app for OSX.  One of the windows in the app has 5 text boxes, some labels and a submit button at the bottom.  The submit button is linked to a method that closes the window, opens a new one and outputs the contents of the text boxes into one text field on the new window.

I had it working correctly, but now when I do anything but click on the top text field the submit method is called and the window closes.  I can click on the black space in the window, but click on any of the objects calls the method.  Also, pressing tab calls the method. I am not sure when I did to cause this error, but any insight or tips would be very useful.

Sorry if this is vague, I'm not even sure how to describe the problem.  If you need any specific information please ask.

Comment: your events are probably being sent via the responder chain to your window or window controller. read up on the responder chain in apple's documentation.

Comment: Did you create your window in Interface Builder (IB)?

Comment: Yup, made with Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking in Interface Builder. Ctrl Click or Right click on the each one of the fields that are responding with calling the function. See if they are linked to the function.

Also check the "responder" as was suggested earlier. You can do this by also right click or ctrl clicking the red responder box labeled "responder". See if anything in there maps to your function

Comment: This worked.  The problem was that the top text box was linked to the method for some reason, so deselecting the field was calling the method.  I must have done it accidentally.